# IE 10 crash in web application

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, crash, internet-explorer-10

Approximately every 10 minutes IE crashes when users work in my application in IE10, i enable crash dumps.
(Web application written with GWT framework and in IE9 it works perfectly)

Info from crash dump:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\LocalDumps\iexplore.exe.9448.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) UP Free x86 compatible
Product: LanManNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Thu Nov 28 05:57:44.000 2013 (UTC + 6:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:22.000
................................................................
......................
Loading unloaded module list
...............
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(24e8.2564): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=0c9e62a0 ebx=03a962c8 ecx=0000194e edx=0f0f3705 esi=0c9e62a0 edi=0ad432e0
eip=6fea94a3 esp=03a96240 ebp=03a9624c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
jscript9!InliningDecider::Inline+0x26:
6fea94a3 f6460d01        test    byte ptr [esi+0Dh],1       ds:002b:0c9e62ad=??
```

Can anybody help me find problem? Does anyone know how to debug such problems?

Update 07.04.2014:

```
02e6a244 6d118e4c jscript9!InliningDecider::Inline+0x2a
02e6a284 6d118d27 jscript9!NativeCodeGenerator::GatherCodeGenData<0>+0xdf
02e6a2e4 6d119003 jscript9!NativeCodeGenerator::GatherCodeGenData+0xd6
02e6a320 6d121ac2 jscript9!NativeCodeGenerator::AddToJitQueue+0x29
02e6a35c 6d10f754 jscript9!NativeCodeGenerator::Prioritize+0x5e
02e6a390 6d10e387 jscript9!JsUtil::BackgroundJobProcessor::PrioritizeJob<NativeCodeGenerator,Js::EntryPointInfo *>+0xea
02e6a3ac 6d10e4a2 jscript9!NativeCodeGenerator::CheckCodeGen+0x59
02e6a3b8 6d110d0c jscript9!NativeCodeGenerator::CheckCodeGenThunk+0xc
02e6a544 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x1bd7
02e6a66c 07154679 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
02e6a678 6d1c5b91 0x7154679
02e6a6b8 6d110d0c jscript9!Js::JavascriptFunction::EntryCall+0xfa
02e6a844 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x1bd7
02e6a97c 07154681 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
02e6a988 6d1c5b91 0x7154681
02e6a9c8 6d110d0c jscript9!Js::JavascriptFunction::EntryCall+0xfa
02e6ab54 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x1bd7
02e6ac64 0715bb39 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
02e6ac70 6d1b0d3b 0x715bb39
02e6acc4 6d1b0ef5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::NewScObject_Helper+0xd6
02e6ace8 6d1b0e81 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::ProfiledNewScObject_Helper+0x55
02e6ae74 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x3d56
02e6af7c 0715bb41 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
02e6af88 6d1103d2 0x715bb41
02e6b114 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0xaab
02e6b21c 0715bb49 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
02e6b228 6d1103d2 0x715bb49
02e6b3b4 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0xaab
02e6b4f4 0715bb61 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
02e6b570 6d121ac2 0x715bb61
02e6b608 6d110d0c jscript9!NativeCodeGenerator::Prioritize+0x5e
02e6b794 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x1bd7
02e6b8bc 0715bbc1 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
02e6b904 6d1a0a83 0x715bbc1
02e6b9a0 6d110d0c jscript9!Js::JavascriptExceptionOperators::OP_TryCatch+0x88
02e6bb34 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x1bd7
02e6bc5c 07158fd1 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
02e6bc68 6d110d0c 0x7158fd1
02e6bdf4 6d10f6d5 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x1bd7
02e6bf0c 07158fd9 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x305
02e6bf40 6d15dd0e 0x7158fd9
02e6c024 6d1a0a83 jscript9!Js::JavascriptFunction::EntryApply+0x25a
02e6c08c 6d2d8b55 jscript9!Js::JavascriptExceptionOperators::OP_TryCatch+0x88
02e6c0d4 6d336e81 jscript9!Js::JavascriptExceptionOperators::OP_TryFinally+0x64
02e6c20c 6afdea7e jscript9!memset+0x5290
02e6c2d8 6d18028e MSHTML!CJScript9Holder::QueryInterface+0x18
02e6c398 6d10ba9b jscript9!Js::JavascriptError::ThrowSyntaxError+0x2b
02e6c3b0 6d10ba70 jscript9!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallRootFunction+0x19
02e6c3f8 6d10b9f8 jscript9!ScriptSite::CallRootFunction+0x40
02e6c424 6d1348da jscript9!ScriptSite::Execute+0x61
02e6c488 6b09755f jscript9!ScriptEngine::Execute+0x115
02e6c4d0 6b097696 MSHTML!CScriptTimers::ExecuteTimer+0x17f
02e6c514 6af52505 MSHTML!CWindow::FireTimeOut+0x3c1
02e6c564 6af52276 MSHTML!CPaintBeat::ProcessTimers+0x1eb
02e6c590 6b33c48b MSHTML!CPaintBeat::OnBeat+0x1aa
02e6c5a0 6b086172 MSHTML!CPaintBeat::OnPaintTimer+0x33
02e6c5b4 6af51e74 MSHTML!CContainedTimerSink<CPaintBeat>::OnTimerMethodCall+0x2e
02e6c60c 6af1a909 MSHTML!GlobalWndOnPaintPriorityMethodCall+0x179
02e6c658 76cdc4e7 MSHTML!GlobalWndProc+0xd3
02e6c684 76cd5f9f user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
02e6c6fc 76cd4f0e user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0xe0
02e6c758 76cd4f7d user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xda
02e6c780 7726702e user32!__fnDWORD+0x24
02e6c7ac 76cd5d0c ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x2e
02e6c7b0 76cd5d33 user32!NtUserDispatchMessage+0xc
02e6c7f4 76cdcc70 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x3d5
02e6c804 6d3f37ff user32!DispatchMessageW+0xf
02e6f988 6d44c800 IEFRAME!CTabWindow::_TabWindowThreadProc+0x4ad
02e6fa48 756a265b IEFRAME!LCIETab_ThreadProc+0x377
02e6fa58 708731a2 iertutil!_IsoThreadProc_WrapperToReleaseScope+0xe
02e6fa7c 75d4ed5c IEShims!NS_CreateThread::DesktopIE_ThreadProc+0x66
02e6fa88 772837eb kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
02e6fac8 772837be ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
02e6fae0 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Comment: This issue is impossible debug in its current state. I'd say try to isolate the users actions. If that seemingly doesn't matter then you should inspect memory usage of your app over time. Chrome does it well. IE vs chrome won't matter as your testing memory usage. Just see if there is a steady rise over time or it remains relatively flat.

Comment: Jquery can be a problem and is your application is live?

Comment: if possible provide us link to application..

Comment: We do not use jquery. The application is very large, we have several megabytes of generated javascript code.

Comment: I would open a support case with Microsoft. They are going to be far more capable of dealing with a crash in the Chakra JavaScript engine than any support you could possibly get on StackOverflow.

You could try running your scripts through a stricter validator such as [JSLint][1].

  [1]: http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: 1) Does the application crash on its own after X time while users are not actively working with it? (But it remains in the active window/tab?). 2) Can you compare memory usage over time between IE10 and another, stable browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Access violation - code c0000005" - this error message indicates that IE is attempting to access a memory address which doesn't exist. Most often this is caused by an unitialized memory location (ie, you're looking at a null reference error) - unfortuantely, this looks like is a null reference error caused in one of the IE libraries, and not in your code.

In increasing order of complexity/decreasing order of likelyhood, you're looking at one of the following problems:

1. you're running out of memory, and running out of it hard, on the machine that IE is running on.
2. you're looking at a hardware issue - some of your memory storage devices are corrupt, and they're corrupting the data that IE is trying to process
3. you've discovered a bug in the compiler that the JSCRIPT9 interpreter is using.

---

To debug these kinds of problems:

1. (2.) use tools to measure the resource use on the machine you're looking at. Make sure that you're not running out of memory. Also, make sure that the problem is reproducible across several machines - eliminate the possibility of a hardware problem.
2. **Get microsoft involved**. See if you can obtain the right tools for [debugging native windows applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/bb980924.aspx). Unfortunately, the IE10sdk tools aren't easy to obtain (i don't think they're publicly available at all?). The most likely fix to your problem is using a different version of ie.

Answer (score 2):

huummm...
It appears that "InliningDecider::Inline" is called and running continues...

A exception must be caught befopre the crash...

Search the error stack for the last open directive "OP_TryFinally" and a close directive "OP_TryCatch"...
from there it should be more info...

in the OS try replacing in the system "jscript9.dll" for a more update version and try it... the same goes for a previous version...

If it is not a system problem my guess (with only this info) would be a faulty JS object... not very commom... but without the code can't say much more...

Comment: I added stack trace just now

Comment: Also in the OS open the event viewer console... then clear all events... force the error and look at the gerated events... a better clue could arise from there...

Comment: If you want to monitor events in realtime go to http://www.nirsoft.net and download "MyEventViewer". it will ease the proposed task in orders of magnitude... you can delete all events in all logs at once... and configure the util to show generated events every second...